# What "[productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1" mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to recreate the redux shopping cart example. But I'm finding it difficult to understand the following line of code as I'm kind of new to ES6 stuff.

[[productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/reducers/cart.js#L29)

Comment: key is value of variable productId, value is (state[productId] or 0 if state[productId] is falsey) + 1

Comment: My glass ball tells me you should look at [computed property named](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)...

Comment: `glass ball` - keep up the good work, and eventually you'll be able to afford a crystal one :p

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the link @ASDFGerte.

Answer (score 1):

Well, read the file again. Here is where `intialState` is created:

```
const initialState = {
  addedIds: [],
  quantityById: {}
}
```

Now is `quantityById` function. It is passed `initialState.quantityById` as `state`.

```
const quantityById = (state = initialState.quantityById, action) => {
```

The following line is using [`spread operator`](http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator) to construct the object to return.

```
      return { ...state,
        [productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1
      }
```

`{ ...state` means take stuff from `state` variable, this will mean all properties will be in new object. Then `[productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1` will set value of *`[productId]`* to value from passed `state` object `state[productId]` or `0` if this id was not on `state` object and add `1` to it.

Overall, this line will add `[productId]` if it is not on passed `state` object or update after it is copied from `state` object.

More information about [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) can be found here as well.

Hope this helps!